# Angular Material, disable floating label when value present

Tags: javascript, css, sass, angular-material

Basically, I want to turn off `md-floating` label (like an animated placeholder in angular material) when there is a value. I have done a similar thing with auto search, in my CSS.

I said if there is a value in the `input` of auto search turns off floating label. I couldn't get it to work with `md-chips`. It is working when typing, but once a `md-chip` is selected the floating label is back because I am not typing any value (*see image below*). But one chip value exists, so if a chip value exists I want no floating label.

[image]

```css
#parent-search-autocomplete{
    margin-bottom:0px;

  & > md-chips-wrap{
    & > md-input-container.md-input-has-value label:not(.md-no-float){
      display:none;
    }

  }
}
```

```html
<form name="parentComponentForm">
<md-chips ng-model="$ctrl.selectedParent" md-autocomplete-snap
    md-transform-chip="$ctrl.transformChip($chip)"
    md-require-match="true"
    md-on-add="$ctrl.updateSelected($ctrl.selectedParent)"
    md-on-remove="$ctrl.updateSelected($ctrl.selectedParent)"
    md-max-chips="{{$ctrl.multiple ? 0 : 1}}">
    <md-autocomplete id="parent-search-autocomplete" flex required  md-input-name="parentComponentField" ng-disabled="$ctrl.disabled"
            md-input-minlength="2"
            md-input-maxlength="25"
            md-selected-item="$ctrl.newAsset.parentComponent"
            md-search-text="$ctrl.searchText"
            md-items="item in $ctrl.querySearch($ctrl.searchText)"
            md-item-text="item.display"
            md-floating-label="{{'PLACEHOLDER.PARENT-COMP-LOC' | translate}}"
            class="my-custom-input">
    <md-item-template>
        <span md-highlight-text="$ctrl.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.display}}</span>
    </md-item-template>
    <div ng-messages="parentComponentForm.parentComponentField.$error" style="color:red">
        <div ng-message="required">You
        <b>must</b>
        have a parent component.</div>
    </div>
</md-autocomplete>

<md-chip-template>
    <span>
        <strong>{{$chip.display}}</strong>
    </span>
</md-chip-template>
</md-chips>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the latest version of angular material you could use floatLabel="never"

See answer in the SO:
[Angular Material, disable floating label when value present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45061202/angular-material-disable-floating-label-when-value-present)